# Sending SMS to multiple numbers at once

Tags: command-line, usb-modem, huawei, sms

How can I send SMS to many numbers at once command via my huawei modem from my laptop, I found the command **mmcli** as my best solution, sending one sms to one number is working fine, but once I tried to send the same text to two numbers or more nothing will heppend even if the response was : successfully created and sent sms, here some of my try

```
sudo mmcli -m 0 --messaging-create-sms="text='test',number='first_number',text='test',number='sencond_number'"

sudo mmcli -m 0 --messaging-create-sms="text='test',number='firstnumbersecondnumber'"
```

These two commands gives me 'successfully created sms' and 'successfully send sms' when sending, but I didn't receive any sms in my phone

if I tried to separate numbers by `,` or `;` it gives me an error  `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Message.InvalidPduParameter: Invalid number`

When I read the [manual](https://linuxcommandlibrary.com/man/mmcli) I didn't find any thing can help me,
I don't want to use for loop ==> this will be my last solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There does not seem to be any way to send multiple SMS messages from a single command. You will need to use a loop.

Comment: @matigo even if I search for another command ?

Comment: The SMS protocol does not support broadcasts to several numbers at the same time. Each needs its own handshake and confirmation. Looking at this logically, either you are creating a loop with `mmcli`, or you are using a different tool that does the loop for you. If the goal is to send as many messages in as short a time as is possible, you will need professional tools such as [Amazon's SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-phone-number-as-subscriber.html). If you are rolling your own solution, then multiple modems will be needed ... with loops.

Comment: @matigo Thanks very much to this detailed comment, it seems I have to use multiples modems with for loop